# Can't get foreach to work correctly in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powerbi

I have been working on a script that basically reads rows from a csv file and publsihes PowerBI reports to workspaces and updating parameters as required. The script works fine and publsihes the reports but for just the first row.

My inspiration is here: https://powerofbi.org/2021/01/27/powershell-script-to-publish-power-bi-reports/

Can anyone tell me why the script doesn't read data from other lines.(line 2 onwards)

```
#Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount before the PS script


[CmdletBinding()]
param
(
   
    [string] $pbixPath

)

[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

$report = Get-ChildItem  $pbixPath

$reportFileToPublish = $report.name

Write-Host "`nReport file to publish: "$reportFileToPublish

$reports = import-csv $PSScriptRoot\publisher.csv

Foreach ($i in $reports) {

    #get report name
    $reportName = $i.report
    $reportFileName = $i.report + ".pbix"

    if ($reportFileToPublish -eq $reportFileName) {
    #report found in the CSV file

        $workspaceName = $i.workspace
        $userName = $i.username
        $parameter1Name = $i.para1name
        $parameter1Value = $i.para1value
        $datasetRefresh = $i.datasetrefresh

        break

    }
}

if (!($userName)) {
Write-Host "`nReport not found in the CSV file!`n"
exit
}
else {
Write-Host "`nUserName: "$userName
}

$credentialsFile = "$PSScriptRoot\data\$userName.txt"

#read username and encrypted password from a file
if (Test-Path $PSScriptRoot\data\$userName.txt) {

    $azure_username = Get-Content $PSScriptRoot\data\$userName.txt -First 1
    $securepassword = (Get-Content $PSScriptRoot\data\$userName.txt -TotalCount 2)[-1] | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

    Write-Host "Stored credentials found"

}
else {

    Write-Host "Stored credentials not found! In the pop up window enter you Azure (Power BI Service) username and password:"
   
    $credential = Get-Credential
    $azure_username = $credential.UserName
    $securepassword = $credential.Password

    $output = $azure_username + "`r`n" + ($securepassword| ConvertFrom-SecureString)
    $output | Set-Content $PSScriptRoot\data\$userName.txt

    Write-Host "Credentials saved"

}

Write-Host "`nSigning in to a Microsoft Azure account:"

#get PSCredential object
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ( $azure_username, $securepassword)
#log in using PSCredential object
Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -Credential $credential

#get workspace by workspace name
$workspaceObject = ( Get-PowerBIWorkspace -Name $workspaceName )
#get #workspace id
$groupid=$workspaceObject.id

#publish a copy of the report (overwrite existing)
$result = New-PowerBIReport -Path $pbixPath -Name $reportName -Workspace $workspaceObject -ConflictAction CreateOrOverwrite
#get report id
$reportid = $result.id

Write-Host "============================================================================`n"
Write-Host -NoNewline "Report: "$reportName" (published)`n`nReport id: "$reportid

Write-Host "`n`nWorkspace id: "$workspaceObject.id

$dataset = Get-PowerBIDataset -Workspace $workspaceObject | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $reportName}
#get dataset
$datasetid = $dataset.id

Write-Host "`nDatasetid: "$dataset.id

$urlbase = "groups/$groupid/datasets/$datasetid/"

#update parameters

if ($parameter1Name) {

    #url and body for UpdateParameters API call
    $url = $urlbase + "UpdateParameters"
 
$body = @"
  {
  "updateDetails": [
    {
      "name": "$parameter1Name",
      "newValue": "$parameter1Value"
    }
  ]
  }
"@
 
    #update parameter's value
    Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url $url -Method Post -Body $body
 
    Write-Host "`n -> parameter '"$parameter1Name"' updated. New value: "$parameter1Value
}
else {
    Write-Host "`nNo parameters to update"
}

#dataset refresh

if ($datasetRefresh -eq "yes") {

#url and body for refreshes API call
  $url=$urlbase + "refreshes"
  $body = @"
  {
    "notifyOption": "NoNotification"
  }
"@
 
# Refresh the dataset
Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url $url -Method Post -Body $body

Write-Host " -> dataset refreshed"

}
else {
    Write-Host "`nDataset refresh not required"
}

Disconnect-PowerBIServiceAccount

Write-Host "`nLogged out"
```

The script is working fine for just the first row. using Powershell 5.1.22621.1778, my PowerBI  MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt is updated and latest.

Comment: Why do you have the `break` in the `ForEach` loop?

Comment: I tried removing the break, and it uploads the last row on the csv file.

Comment: You do some processing within the `ForEach` loop - which the `break` is killing - but you don't appear to save or otherwise accumulate the data you're processing. Think carefully about what you want to accomplish, then look and see if your script is actually doing that.

Comment: In particular, think about what work the script is supposed to do with each of the reports retrieved.  As it is, with the break removed, you are just passing it down the pipeline.  That is  probably why the last record is appearing on your screen.

Comment: That's what I need help in, how to move to the next row, I am sorry I am not a scripting person

Comment: Have you tried to use the `continue` instead of `break`?